# Why web3 filter not valid?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I use the following code to monitor contract events, but the filter has no effect. I still saw all the information that triggered the Transfer event in the callback function, without any filtering.

```
//监听
myContractInstance.events.Transfer({
    filter: { receiver: this.state.accountAddress }, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function (error, event) {
    console.log("监听结果：");
    console.log(event);
    message.info(event.returnValues.sender + " 向你转账了：" + event.returnValues.value);

})
    .on('data', function (event) {

        // console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
    })
    .on('changed', function (event) {
        // remove event from local database
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
```

> returnValues: Result 0: "0x3C2a3A26910429D88b134e4d9bCbf6bA2D188Ac9"
> 1: "0x3C2a3A26910429D88b134e4d9bCbf6bA2D188Ac9" 2: "你好啊" message:
> "你好啊" receiver: "0x3C2a3A26910429D88b134e4d9bCbf6bA2D188Ac9" sender:
> "0x3C2a3A26910429D88b134e4d9bCbf6bA2D188Ac9"

similar question ： [How to filter by string parameter , web3 2.0.0-alpha.1 Solidity events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523392/how-to-filter-by-string-parameter-web3-2-0-0-alpha-1-solidity-events)

Comment: This is an English-speaking platform. Don't post the question in a different langue (even if it is in addition to the English one)

Comment: Is the `receiver` an indexed parameter? If you're not sure, please post the event definition (from the contract source code or from the ABI JSON).

Comment: this is my  abi json code:                                                                                                                             {
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [
   {
    "indexed": false,
    "internalType": "address",
    "name": "sender",
    "type": "address"
   },
   {
    "indexed": false,
    "internalType": "address",
    "name": "receiver",
    "type": "address"
   },
   {
    "indexed": false,
    "internalType": "uint256",
    "name": "value",
    "type": "uint256"
   }
  ],
  "name": "Transfer",
  "type": "event"
 },

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in github : https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/535

error code:
event SendMessage(address sender,address receiver,string message);

correct code:
event SendMessage(address indexed sender,address indexed receiver,string indexed message);